# Email retrieved from an HTML page

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to retrieve an email address from a HTML page using PHP. I have a page in where I have various questions(survey page). This survey page is accessed by a link I have sent to users on their email address. I want that when the user clicks the link after logging into the his email address and filling out the survey form, that email address should be pushed to phpmyadmin database ?

Comment: without the users entering their email address? you want somehow the email to be retrieved from the email message you send thema fter they click on the link to the survey?

Comment: it's called using a `WHERE` clause. Plus, no code is guesswork or has everyone writing the code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The survey page is accessed by a link I have sent to users on their
>   email address.

Why don't you send something like appending their email in link?

```
<a href="surverypage.php?email=toemailaddress@to.com">Click here to fill the survey</a>
```

And in the survey form, access the get `email` value and insert it to database. You can access the email by,

```
$user_email = $_GET['email'];
```

SIMPLE!

**EDIT :**

survey.php (where user clicks this page in email)

```
<?php

$user_email = $_GET['email'];

// get all survey answers with POST and insert them with SQL query

?>
```

Make sure, the link you send to user's email address must have dynamic URL link like,

```
<a href="surverypage.php?email=toemailaddress@to.com">Click here to fill the survey</a>
```

> ```
> toemailaddress@to.com
> ```

This part changes dynamically. Just replace this with recipient email address.

Comment: Can you share the code with me ? with the basic php page please ....

Comment: @SushantUbalePatil Updated. Check it out.

Comment: I don't want to send the email in the link. I want that when user logs into his email address, his email address should be sent to me when the user finishes his survey....